# Oracle SQL Developer - Map view disabled

Tags: dictionary, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a few tables in Oracle 19c with SDO_GEOMETRY column. I am trying to get a spatial view of it using SQL Developer but the option is not enabled. It is valid geometry data and I verified it using SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT. What am I missing?
[image: Screenshot of SQL Developer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That picture is horrible, but I can tell what you're trying to show.

The answer comes down to how the Java libraries are loaded...at the time you do that right-click, not all of the Spatial libraries are available. You can 'force' this to work by first opening the Spatial viewer.

View > Map View

[image]

Once you've done this, try again.

Comment: Thank you so much. I opened the Map View and had to execute some SQL on it before it would enable the option.